# java output to a file and bar chart

Tags: java

I have this code that I'm producing...

I want to show the results as follows:

1) output to a .PDF & .TXT file.
2) Create a Bar Chart (in color) of the results.

Is this possible?

```
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class TEXTTEXT_BarChart {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int numberOfStores = 5;
            String userStringInput;
            double storeSales;
            int numberofHundredDollarDivisions;
            String outputString = "SALES BAR CHART\n";

            for (int store = 1; store <= numberOfStores; store++) {
                userStringInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter today's sales for store " + store);
                storeSales = Double.parseDouble(userStringInput);
                numberofHundredDollarDivisions = (int) (storeSales / 100);
                outputString += "Store" + store + ": ";
                for (int printAsterisk = 1; printAsterisk <= numberofHundredDollarDivisions; printAsterisk++) {
                    outputString += "*";
                }
                outputString += "\n";
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputString);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is java code

Comment: This is not JavaScript, this is Java, please edit the tags and format your code correctly using Ctrl+K after selecting the entire code section.

Comment: Did you try to search before posting ?

Comment: I have but nothing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19562370/5624464 please check this here they have given solution

Answer (score -1):

To answer you first question, you can use itext dependencies for creating pdf documents

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Check this [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/itext-read-and-write-pdf-in-java/) for creating a pdf file programmatically.
And to write the txt file you can directly use the `FileOutputStream` . Again you can refer this [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-fileoutputstream-example/)

For 2nd question you can use [JFreeChart](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jfreechart/jfreechart_bar_chart.htm)

Comment: I see the codes but how do I incorporate this with my current code?

Comment: I am afraid that is something which you need to figure out. In case you are getting any problem you can raise another question or else search for the existing answers

Comment: How do i modify the text file itself?

Comment: you can use fileoutputstream to append data or to edit some data. Go through it's doc first https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html

Comment: @dhoctran ok please consider accepting solution in case you find it useful.